# Missing some window icons in Lubuntu 16.04

Tags: lubuntu, icons

Installed Lubuntu 16.04 64bit freshly on my laptop and now some windows does not have their own icons, so it makes finding right window much more difficult.

On screenshot below you could see, that Brackets and Konsole miss their original icons, but Chromium is OK. Still, in start-menu they all are represented with their own icons

[image: Brackets and Konsole missing icons]

How to fix this?